# Angular 2 @ViewChild selector function

Tags: angular

According to the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b1f8eb14c8cd1f415b07d72e09d14bed77c8d4ac/packages/core/src/metadata/di.ts#L234), the selector for `@ViewChild` (or `@ViewChildren`, `@ContentChild` and `@ContentChildren`) can take one of three parameter types as the first parameter:

1. A string
2. A type
3. A function

The first two are easy.  I can't figure out how to do the third, though.  I've tried:

`@ContentChild(() => this.templB ) tmplFromFunc: TemplateRef<any>;` which doesn't throw an error, but `tmplFromFunc` is undefined even though `this.templB` has a value (when checked in DevTools)

Tried adding `forwardRef`:
`@ContentChild(forwardRef(() => this.templB )) tmplFromFunc: TemplateRef<any>;` with no difference

Tried removing the arrow function and using an explicit function, which only returns this.tmplB:
`@ContentChild( this.getTemplateRef ) tmplFromFunc: TemplateRef<any>;` which throws an error: **Can't construct a query for the property "tmplFromFunc" of "MyComponent" since the query selector wasn't defined.**  Looking up that error didn't get me anything useful/relevant.

Tried adding `forwardRef` here:
`@ContentChild( forwardRef(this.getTemplateRef) ) tmplFromFunc: TemplateRef<any>;` which gave the error **Cannot set property '__forward_ref__' of undefined**

And also tried `@ContentChild( this.getTemplateRef() ) tmplFromFunc: TemplateRef<any>;` just for fun, which returns a different error: **this.getTemplateRef is not a function**

So I tried adding forwardRef here:
`@ContentChild( forwardRef(this.getTemplateRef()) ) tmplFromFunc: TemplateRef<any>;` which also throws **this.getTemplateRef is not a function**

After beating my head against this all afternoon, I'm kind of at a loss of what to try next.  Has anyone ever gotten a function working as the selector and if so, can you share some code or point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.